# Ms Access Assign Dynamic Caption to Label and Textfields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 8 Labels & Textboxes `name :Label21, Label22 .. Labe28.Textboxes as Txt21, Txt22 .. Txt28.`

For some reasons the label & the text box names cannot be changed. For some Valid reasons the value for `For loop`  ( -7 to 0 ) cannot be changed.

I want to change Caption of the Label so the caption changes to Label21=whatever1, Label22=whatever2.

I thought of adding an Array with a fixed length of 8 and adding values dynamically to that array and print it in another loop but not sure how to loop in the negative value.

What I have tried is below.

```
For i = -7 To 0
     Me("Label" & i).Caption = "whatever"&i
     Me("Txt" & i).Caption = "whatever"&i
Next i
```

**If I add one more For loop inside the current For loop, it won't do the needful, not sure if I should EXIT For loop somewhere.**

```
  For i = -7 To 0
        For j = 21 To 28
          Me("Label" & j).Caption = "whatever"&i
          Me("Txt" & j).Caption = "whatever"&i
        Next J 
Next i
```

Comment: the loop will still go through the numbers just the same, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0

Comment: do you have a label-7 ?

Comment: @justkrys no i dont have label-7, the labels are Label21, Label22 .. Labe28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 21
For i = -7 To 0
     Controls("Label" & counter).Caption = "whatever" & i
     Controls("Txt" & counter).Caption = "whatever" & i
     counter = counter + 1
Next i
```

Comment: glad I could be of assistance.